# Adding a property next to the avatar

Tags: feature-request

Can we add a text/property showing next to the avatar? That would be native/non-native speaker so that we can give more tolerance to non-native speaker like me. I always think that while asking about meaning on a particular phrase/word, some users might think "What kind of stupid question is this?"

Comment: Related: [Stack sites must support primary and secondary language when defining user profile](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/101/).

Answer (score 1):

You can always report in your user profile that you are not a native English speaker.

I don't think there is another SE site where being a native English speaker is relevant. Maybe it can make sense to report on an SE site about a language that you are not a native speaker of that language, but reporting that doesn't make sense to report that for sites like Stack Overflow, and Super User.

There are some problems I see with this such field. As the profile can be copied to another SE site, what would "I am not a native speaker" mean in other SE sites? If I am on the *Italian Language and Usage* site, what would it mean? Would it be relevant for that site that you are not a native English speaker?
Considering users that are native speakers of two different languages, I see difficult to catch all the possibilities in a field.

Then, there must be a reason, if a similar field is not already set in the user profiles.

Comment: the SE sites shares the same system?

Comment: @gunbuster363 Yes, they do. The only site that uses different code is [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).